# Edit button on card inside listview Builder Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to create a list of cards each with a button that displays a menu (edit, delete ...) but I don't know where to start or which widget to use. There is also the problem that each button must respond individually.

I use Hive for my card data

Do you know how to do it ?

```
 Align(
  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 4.29,
    height: 16,
    child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/Icones/IconesNewDesign/edit.svg', width: 4.29, height: 16,fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
  ),
 ),
```

Edit:

I need something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use ListTiles with PopupMenuButtons
[image: I did not quite understand the question but if you want something like this]

```
final List<String> _cards = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];

ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _cards.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
            elevation: 5,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(_cards[index]),
              trailing: PopupMenuButton(
                itemBuilder: (ctx) => [
                  PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Delete")),
                  PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Edit")),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Of course you should precise the values on each `PopupMenuItem` and an `onSelect` method. Read more about `PopupMenuBotton` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is, I need to use my custom card. That's why it's a complicate question

Comment: @bchoisy You could copy the ListTile in my code above and pass it to your custom Card as a child

Comment: I just edited my post to describe what I have in mind a little better

Comment: @bchoisy can I know the properties of the custom card?

Answer (score 0):

***first you need to take listviewbuilder and then take card inside it and you can also take icons of delte and edit in card***

```
 ListView.builder(
    itemcount;2,
    itembuilder(context,index)
    {
     retun Card(
       child:Column(
    childern[
      Image.Asset(""),
    Row(
    childern[
    Icon(Icons.delte),
    Spacer(),
    Icon(Icons.edit),
    ]
    )
    
    ]
    )
    )
    )
```

Comment: I would like to do like popupmenu button but for each card of my listViewBuidler